# What are the "things above, where Christ is seated" as said in Colossians 3:1-2?

Tags: word-study, historical-interpretation, authorial-intent, pauline-epistles, colossians

What are the **"things above, where Christ is seated"** as said in

> Colossians 3:1-2 If then you have been raised with Christ, seek the
>   things that are above, where Christ is, seated at the right hand of
>   God. 2 Set your minds on things that are above, not on things that are
>   on earth.( ESV )

?

Answer (score 1):

Those "things above" belong likely and entirely both to God the Father and the Son, and this is the meaning of the metaphor "at the right hand of God": "right hand" means the parallel dimension, or equality of the Father and the Son.

Now, what are those "things" that belong likely to the Father and the Son? Surely divine uncreated features, like love, wisdom, power, glory, justice, purity etc. all those features of which God makes also humans partakers (cf. 2 Peter 1:4).

Answer (score 1):

**What are the “things above where Christ is seated” as said in Colossians 3:1-2?**

By being faithful to the end and giving his sinless human body as sacrifice for our  sins, God exalted him to a higher position and bestowed him with  a name greater that any other .(Philipians 2:9)    Sitting at the right hand of God, is a position of honor, with angels and powers made subject to him.(Except God) Also by means of Jesus, God will exercise his "will on earth" (Matthew 6:10), so that all things in heaven and on earth will be unified under Christ.

Things above where Christ is seated.

Psalm 110:1  (NASB)

**The Lord Gives Dominion to the King.**

> 110 "The Lord (God) says to my Lord(Jesus the King): “Sit at My right
>   hand Until I make Your enemies a footstool for Your feet.”

**The enemies of God: "The wicked man will be no more."**

Psalm 37:10-11 (NASB)

> 10 "Yet a little while and the wicked man will be no more; And you
>   will look carefully for his place and he will not be there.  11 But
>   the humble will inherit the land  And will delight themselves in
>   abundant prosperity."

**Sitting at the right hand of God, a position of authority.**

1 Peter 3:22 (NASB)

> 22 "Who is at the right hand of God, having gone into heaven, after
>   angels and authorities and powers had been subjected to Him."

Jesus, raised from the dead ,  granted immortality, given the keys of death and hades-the keys are symbolic of the power given to Jesus, to resurrect people from the confines of the grave.

Romans 6:9  (NASB)

> 9 "Knowing that Christ, having been raised from the dead, is never to
>   die again; death no longer is master over Him."

Revelation 1:17-18  (NASB)

> 17 "When I saw Him, I fell at His feet like a dead man. And He placed
>   His right hand on me, saying, “Do not be afraid; I am the first and
>   the last, 18 and the living One; and I [a]was dead, and behold, **I am
>   alive forevermore, and I have the keys of death and of Hades."**

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing "*above where* Christ is," but there are *things "above*, where Christ is seated at the right hand of God." Christ is in heaven, and St. Paul is contrasting things that are above from those below: "Set your minds on things that are above, not on things that are on earth." He isn't speaking of a place above God or Christ.

EDIT: As others have kindly pointed out, if English is not your first language, the punctuation will through you off here. The comma of the ESV ("where Christ is, seated at the right hand of God") attempts to create two separate details of interest: where Christ is, and what He's doing there, whereas it is really one thought: 'the place where Christ is, above, i.e., in heaven.'

Comment: The OP is from India and English is his second language. I think he understands what you are saying and I do not think he was under the impression that you have implied, myself.I would suggest that the ESV punctuation is at fault, not the OP.

Comment: Thanks @SolaGratia, NigelJ is right

Comment: I see. I've edited the answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

"Things are above" versus "Things are on earth" by the author. We can list down few things are on earth as example:

1.) Money

2.) Houses

3.) Pets

These are few simple things that are on earth. Things of the world. I would say they are the material we are chasing for. Even the reputation we are trying hard to gain in different field.

Things are above + where Christ is seated. At the right hand of God. The right hand may symbolize authority or power. I would say the things are referring to God's Work. The things that God is doing through Jesus Christ on earth. What are those things? When you are called to serve Jesus, to serve in church, to serve in mission field, to serve in many other fields, those are the place where you can see the Work of God. Miracles, wonders, things that God do that glorifies the name of The Father. Salvation itself is a great miracle!

I believe that the author is calling the audience to serve the Lord, to seek God's Will. Instead of spending our time on earth to build our own "empire" rather than the Kingdom of God.

Answer (score 0):

First consider the context. In Colossians 2, the church was directed away from focusing on eating certain foods, keeping feasts, or the Sabbath. Verse 17 says these are but a shadow of things to come; things above. Chapter 2 concludes talking about legalism related to things on earth; “Do not touch, do not taste, do not handle”, which again concern things which perish; things on the earth.

In the Gospels, Jesus told us to “lay up for yourselves treasures in heaven.” Matt 19:21. Col 3 restates this to slaves, telling them to serve their masters heartily so they “will receive the reward of the inheritance.”

In Revelation's letters to the seven churches, Jesus tells the churches what to set their minds on.  To those who overcome, Jesus promises the following;

• Food from the tree of life.

• Deliverance from the second death.

• Hidden mana, a white stone with a new name.

• Power and authority of over the nations;

• the morning star.

• White garments;

• your name permanently in the Book of Life;

• Jesus confessing your name before the Father and the angels.

• Jesus will make the overcomers a pillar in the temple of God. Jesus will write on them the name of God and the name of the city of God, the New Jerusalem.

• We will sit with Jesus on His throne.
These things are worth overcoming for.  These things are worth setting our minds on. Then Revelation gives us more things above to seek.

The scriptures give us more things to set our minds on. 1 John 3:2-3 speaks  of having the hope of our new bodies. Romans 5:1-2 speaks about rejoicing in "the hope of the glory of God."  Daniel spoke of this future glory, saying; "Those who are wise shall shine like the brightness of the firmament, and those who turn many to righteousness, like the stars forever and ever." Dan 12:3. Colossians 3:4 says we will appear with Him in glory.